# HighCharts .NET X-Axis definition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, dotnethighcharts

I have a list with values. I want to show a HighCharts .NET chart based on these values. The problem is: I have to set the chart properties in my code. It looks like this:

```
  Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart");

            chart.SetXAxis(new XAxis
            {
                Categories = new[] { results.date[0], results.date[1], results.date[2] }
            });

            chart.SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Data = new Data(new object[]
                    {results.Values[0], results.Values[1], results.Values[2]})
            });
```

So now, the chart only work if my list contains three values. But maybe the list has 20, 40, or more values. How can i code that?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
            chart.SetXAxis(new[]
            {
                new XAxis { Categories = results.Date.ToArray()}
            });

            chart.SetSeries(
                new Series
                {
                    Data = new Data(results.Values.Cast<object>().ToArray())
                }
            );
```